# Return json string from html list

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I got an html document with an html list in it:

```
<body>
<p>Once upon a time, there were <a
href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three_Little_Pigs">three little pigs</a>:</p>
<ol>
  <li><h2>Pig A</h2>
  </li>
  <li><h2>Pig B</h2>
  </li>
  <li><h2>Pig C</h2>
  </li>
</ol>
```

I want to return the three pigs listed below 'there were three little pigs'
in a JSON string which looks like '["Pig A", "Pig B", "Pig C"]'

I have tried to use find_all and re

```
def get_pigs():
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')
    pigs = soup.body.contents[3].find_all('h2')
    import re
    p_list = soup.find(text=re.compile("Pig "))
    print(p_list)
get_pigs()
```

My code gives me only Pig A. I don't know why this does not give me the result I expected, and how could I get the right result?

Comment: What result are you getting now?

Comment: The result now is Pig A

Comment: Try `p_list = soup.find_all(text=re.compile("Pig "))`. You were calling `soup.find(...)` which will only return the first match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to extract the `.text` from each element found in the `soup` method `find_all`, then you will just need to `json.dumps` this list

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json

def get_pigs(html_doc):
  soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')
  pigs = [elem.text for elem in soup.find_all('h2')]
  return pigs
pigs=get_pigs(open("pigs.html").read())
print(pigs)
print("json string:",json.dumps(pigs))
```

output:

```
['Pig A', 'Pig B', 'Pig C']
json string: ["Pig A", "Pig B", "Pig C"]
```

[Working code](https://repl.it/@giulianooliveira/ilila)

Comment: Thanks! I just added the .text to my code and it's correct.